# Mimicking T9 cell messaging

Tags: c, programming-challenge, comparative-review

Today I solved a question from Google Code Jam: mimicking a cell phone keypad messaging.

Here is the program, with `goto` statements.  I know it is an unstructured style to use `goto`, but I still did because it improved speed.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char c, c1 = NULL;
    int top;

    top:
    while((c = getchar()) != '\n')
    {
        if (c == ' ')printf("0");

        if(c == 'a' || c == 'b' || c == 'c')
        {
           if(c1 == 'a' || c1 == 'b' || c1 == 'c')
           printf(" ");
          if(c == 'a') printf("2");
          if(c == 'b') printf("22");
          if(c == 'c') printf("222");
           c1 = c;
            goto top;

        }


         if(c == 'd' || c == 'e' || c == 'f')
        {
          if(c1 == 'd' || c1 == 'e' || c1 == 'f')
           printf(" ");
          if(c == 'd') printf("3");
          if(c == 'e') printf("33");
          if(c == 'f') printf("333");
           c1 = c;
            goto top;


        }

         if(c == 'g' || c == 'h' || c == 'i')
        {
            if(c1 == 'g' || c1 == 'h' || c1 == 'i')
           printf(" ");

          if(c == 'g') printf("4");
          if(c == 'h') printf("44");
          if(c == 'i') printf("444");
           c1 = c;
            goto top;

        }



         if(c == 'j' || c == 'k' || c == 'l')
        {
            if(c1 == 'j' || c1 == 'k' || c1 == 'l')
           printf(" ");

          if(c == 'j') printf("5");
          if(c == 'k') printf("55");
          if(c == 'l') printf("555");
           c1 = c;
            goto top;


        }

         if(c == 'm' || c == 'n' || c == 'o')
        {
            if(c1 == 'm' || c1 == 'n' || c1 == 'o')
           printf(" ");

          if(c == 'm') printf("6");
          if(c == 'n') printf("66");
          if(c == 'o') printf("666");
           c1 = c;
            goto top;


        }

          if(c == 'p' || c == 'q' || c == 'r' || c == 's')
        {
            if(c1 == 'p' || c1 == 'q' || c1 == 'r' || c1 == 's')
           printf(" ");

          if(c == 'p') printf("7");
          if(c == 'q') printf("77");
          if(c == 'r') printf("777");
          if(c == 's') printf("7777");
           c1 = c;
            goto top;

        }

          if(c == 't' || c == 'u' || c == 'v')
        {
            if(c1 == 't' || c1 == 'u' || c1 == 'v')
           printf(" ");

          if(c == 't') printf("8");
          if(c == 'u') printf("88");
          if(c == 'v') printf("888");
           c1 = c;
           goto top;

        }

          if(c == 'w' || c == 'x' || c == 'y' || c == 'z')
        {
            if(c1 == 'w' || c1 == 'x' || c1 == 'y' || c1 == 'z')
           printf(" ");
          if(c == 'w') printf("9");
          if(c == 'x') printf("99");
          if(c == 'y') printf("999");
          if(c == 'z') printf("9999");
           c1 = c;
          goto top;

        }
    }
}
```

The above program without `goto`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char c, c1 = NULL;

    while((c = getchar()) != '\n')
    {
        if (c == ' ')printf("0");

        if(c == 'a' || c == 'b' || c == 'c')
        {
           if(c1 == 'a' || c1 == 'b' || c1 == 'c')
           printf(" ");
          if(c == 'a') printf("2");
          if(c == 'b') printf("22");
          if(c == 'c') printf("222");

        }


         if(c == 'd' || c == 'e' || c == 'f')
        {
          if(c1 == 'd' || c1 == 'e' || c1 == 'f')
           printf(" ");
          if(c == 'd') printf("3");
          if(c == 'e') printf("33");
          if(c == 'f') printf("333");


        }

         if(c == 'g' || c == 'h' || c == 'i')
        {
            if(c1 == 'g' || c1 == 'h' || c1 == 'i')
           printf(" ");

          if(c == 'g') printf("4");
          if(c == 'h') printf("44");
          if(c == 'i') printf("444");

        }



         if(c == 'j' || c == 'k' || c == 'l')
        {
            if(c1 == 'j' || c1 == 'k' || c1 == 'l')
           printf(" ");

          if(c == 'j') printf("5");
          if(c == 'k') printf("55");
          if(c == 'l') printf("555");


        }

         if(c == 'm' || c == 'n' || c == 'o')
        {
            if(c1 == 'm' || c1 == 'n' || c1 == 'o')
           printf(" ");

          if(c == 'm') printf("6");
          if(c == 'n') printf("66");
          if(c == 'o') printf("666");


        }

          if(c == 'p' || c == 'q' || c == 'r' || c == 's')
        {
            if(c1 == 'p' || c1 == 'q' || c1 == 'r' || c1 == 's')
           printf(" ");

          if(c == 'p') printf("7");
          if(c == 'q') printf("77");
          if(c == 'r') printf("777");
          if(c == 's') printf("7777");

        }

          if(c == 't' || c == 'u' || c == 'v')
        {
            if(c1 == 't' || c1 == 'u' || c1 == 'v')
           printf(" ");

          if(c == 't') printf("8");
          if(c == 'u') printf("88");
          if(c == 'v') printf("888");


        }

          if(c == 'w' || c == 'x' || c == 'y' || c == 'z')
        {
            if(c1 == 'w' || c1 == 'x' || c1 == 'y' || c1 == 'z')
           printf(" ");
          if(c == 'w') printf("9");
          if(c == 'x') printf("99");
          if(c == 'y') printf("999");
          if(c == 'z') printf("9999");


        }

        c1 = c;
    }
}
```

Which one is better?  How can I come to a realization that X program is better compared to Y?

By the way, I did not use any Derived data typed and pointers because I did not find it useful here.

Answer (score 2):

Terminating when `getchar()` encounters `\n` is poor practice.  If the program encounters <kbd>EOF</kbd> before <kbd>Newline</kbd>, then it will enter an infinite loop.

Considering that you only support lowercase, it would be nice if you folded the input to lowercase.

That is one long, uninspired while-loop, full of cut-and-paste code.  I recommend a completely different approach.  Defining a `print_t9()` function makes the code more meaningful and reusable.

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

/**
 * Determines the key and the number of repetitions of that key to type
 * character c in T9.  If c is a supported character, returns true.
 * If c is unsupported, returns false, and the contents of *key and *reps
 * are undefined.
 */
static _Bool t9_lookup(char c, int *key, int *reps) {
    static const char t9_table[][5] = {
                " ",            /*   0   */
        "",     "abc", "def",   /* 1 2 3 */
        "ghi",  "jkl", "mno",   /* 4 5 6 */
        "pqrs", "tuv", "wxyz"   /* 7 8 9 */
    };

    c = tolower(c);
    for (*key = 0; *key < sizeof(t9_table); (*key)++) {
        char *p;
        if ((p = strchr(t9_table[*key], c))) {
            if (reps) {
                *reps = p - t9_table[*key] + 1;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

/**
 * If c is one of the supported characters, prints the T9 representation and
 * returns true.  Otherwise, returns false.  If the T9 representation uses the
 * same key as the previous character, a space is printed as a separator.
 */
_Bool print_t9(FILE *output, char c, char prev_c) {
    int key, reps, prev_key;
    if (!t9_lookup(c, &key, &reps)) return false;

    if (t9_lookup(prev_c, &prev_key, NULL) && key == prev_key) {
        fprintf(output, " ");
    }
    while (reps--) {
        fprintf(output, "%d", key);
    }
    return true;
}

int main() {
    for (char prev_c = '\0', c; EOF != (c = getchar()); prev_c = c) {
        print_t9(stdout, c, prev_c) || putchar(c);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

You should probably support digits as well, to be typed with one additional keypress.  All it would take to support that enhancement is a simple change:

```
    static const char t9_table[][6] = {
                 " 0",
        "1",     "abc2", "def3",
        "ghi4",  "jkl5", "mno6",
        "pqrs7", "tuv8", "wxyz9"
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

I didn't write any C in the last few years but I think you could use [`continue`](http://www.acm.uiuc.edu/webmonkeys/book/c_guide/1.6.html#continue) instead of `goto` in the first version.

Comment: continue looks correct

Answer (score 0):

Because your outer-layer tests are mutually exclusive (ie. only one can occur), you should use `else` rather than `goto` or `continue`. The `else` is used when the condition for which `if` tests is false:

```
    if (c == ' ') {
        printf("0");
    }
    else if (c == 'a' || c == 'b' || c == 'c')
    {
        if(c1 == 'a' || c1 == 'b' || c1 == 'c')
            printf(" ");
        if(c == 'a') printf("2");
        else if(c == 'b') printf("22");
        else if(c == 'c') printf("222");
        c1 = c;
    }
    else if(c == 'd' || c == 'e' || c == 'f')
    { ... }
    else if ...
etc
```

note also that `c` and `c1` should be declared `int` and that `c1 = NULL` is wrong (as `NULL` is declared as `(void *) 0`; use `c1 = '\0'`.

Moreover, turn more warnings ON in your compiler.